# std::function and lambda not respecting reference requirement

Tags: c++, std-function

```
using viref_func = std::function<void(int& intref)>;
viref_func f1 = [](int foo) { ++foo; };
viref_func f2 = [](auto foo) { ++foo; };
viref_func f3 = [](int& foo) { ++foo; };
viref_func f4 = [](auto& foo) { ++foo; };

int test(0);
f1(test);
f2(test);
f3(test);
f4(test);
```

I half and half understand why `f1` and `f2` are valid (and analogous) code (but not "working as I want it to").

How can I make `f1` fail compilation, requiring an int reference?

I don't care much if `f2` fail or compiles, but if it compiles, the auto variable should be an int reference and not an int. It becoming an auto int ref would be the preferred way out.

`f3` and `f4` work as intended.

Addendum: references in std::function are used in my library code in a number of places. I want to make it easy on consumers of said library to catch dumb mistakes. I don't mind adding complexity in the library. I want to avoid making it hard on consumers of the library. A user having "auto" on a parameter rather than "auto&" (or proper_type&) caused a lot of problems at the user, and for me helping to track down the bug.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61662210/9535211

Comment: @Axel.A it's about the same issue, but it's a different question entirely. That other question isn't asking how to make a non-reference fail compilation. it's asking about insight into the why/how.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap `int` to be uncopyable, but that requires changes to both the call site and the functions:

```
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
struct uncopyable
{
    T value;
    uncopyable(T value) : value(value) {}
    uncopyable(const uncopyable &) = delete;
    uncopyable(uncopyable &&) = delete;
    uncopyable& operator=(const uncopyable &) = delete;
    uncopyable& operator=(uncopyable &&) = delete;
};

int main()
{
    using viref_func = std::function<void(uncopyable<int>& intref)>;
    // viref_func f1 = [](int foo) { ++foo; }; // error as desired
    // viref_func f2 = [](auto foo) { ++foo; }; // also an error
    viref_func f3 = [](uncopyable<int>& foo) { ++foo.value; };
    viref_func f4 = [](auto& foo) { ++foo.value; };
    
    uncopyable<int> test(0);
    f3(test);
    f4(test);
}
```

[See it on coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f5ebd5381953781)

Comment: interesting approach... usable in a couple places where the reference is already an object (which maybe should be actually uncopyable anyway). Not really usefull in most places, adds too much effort on the caller side of things.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make f1 fail compilation, requiring an int reference?

Cast the lambda to your type.

```
#include <functional>
using viref_func_type = void (int& intref);
using viref_func = std::function<viref_func_type>;

viref_func_type *f11 = [](int foo) { ++foo; }; // error
viref_func f1 = f11;

viref_func f2 = static_cast<viref_func_type*>([](int foo) { ++foo; }); // error

template <typename> struct fn_sig;
template <typename T> struct fn_sig<std::function<T>> { using type = T; };
viref_func f3 = static_cast<fn_sig<viref_func>::type*>([](int foo) { ++foo; }); // error
```

Comment: ok, it works... but it kinda defeats the purpose... if the coder calling the function makes the effort of going through that cast... they probably were smart enough to use a ref in the first place.
I don't mind adding extra stuff on the definition side to trap inappropriate use...
I'm not looking to make life harder on the users of the functionality (I'm trying to make it easier on them by trapping errors).

Comment: This fails to accept `[](auto& foo) { ++foo; }`

Answer (score 1):

`std::function` allows implicit conversions between the declared parameters and bound functor's parameters (ditto result types). You could write a variation yourself that required an exact match.

```
template <typename F, typename R, typename... Args>
concept exact_invokable = 
    requires () { static_cast<R(F::*)(Args...)>(&F::operator()); } ||
    requires () { static_cast<R(F::*)(Args...) const>(&F::operator()); } ||
    requires () { static_cast<R(F::*)(Args...) &>(&F::operator()); } ||
    requires () { static_cast<R(F::*)(Args...) const &>(&F::operator()); } ||
    std::same_as<F, R(*)(Args...)>;

template <typename F>
class exact_function;

template <typename R, typename... Args>
class exact_function<R(Args...)> : std::function<R(Args...)>
{
    template <typename F>
    static std::function<R(Args...)> to_function(F f)
    {
        if constexpr (requires () { static_cast<R(F::*)(Args...)>(&F::operator()); }) 
            return std::bind_front(static_cast<R(F::*)(Args...)>(&F::operator()), f);
        if constexpr (requires () { static_cast<R(F::*)(Args...) const>(&F::operator()); }) 
            return std::bind_front(static_cast<R(F::*)(Args...) const>(&F::operator()), f);
        if constexpr (requires () { static_cast<R(F::*)(Args...) &>(&F::operator()); }) 
            return std::bind_front(static_cast<R(F::*)(Args...) &>(&F::operator()), f);
        if constexpr (requires () { static_cast<R(F::*)(Args...) const &>(&F::operator()); }) 
            return std::bind_front(static_cast<R(F::*)(Args...) const &>(&F::operator()), f);
        return f;
    }

public:
    template<exact_invokable<R, Args...> F>
    exact_function(F f) : std::function<R(Args...)>(to_function(f)) {}
    
    using std::function<R(Args...)>::operator();
};
```

[See it on coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e0bc2df7a7e475e2)

Comment: It works!  It's not immediately obvious how it does what it does.  Care to elaborate ?  P.S. It does cause a C4702: unreachable code on the 'return f;' line. in VS2022

Comment: @oreubens `return f` shouldn't be unreachable, it matches the case where you pass a free function. It's 6 variations on "force `R operator()(Args...)` to be the `operator()` that is bound in the `std::function`"

Comment: @oreubens upon further testing, the `&&` parts aren't needed because that can't be wrapped in a `std::function`. See https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/451a8190d9da4a83

Comment: apparently for all cases taken by one of the if conditions, VS2022 is smart enough to see that the end return f can not be called so generates a C4702.
Not a huge problem, a #pragma warning will fix that. :)
exact_function passed through the unit tests (which we had for std::function), even caught an issue in one of the tests...
It's unclear atm how big of an impact this will have on our customer's code bases.  More testing needed, looks promising.